# It seems that '.getElementsByClassName' called twice

Tags: javascript

I'd like to manipulate DOM of youtube for hiding unwanted videos, and I'm struggling with the error 
`'innerText' of undefined`.

These are the source code of the problematic part, `SidebarItems` is the array that has "related videos" elements while playing video.

[image]

```
  var SidebarItems = document.getElementsByClassName('video-list-item');

  for(_count = 0; _count < SidebarItems.length; _count++)
  {
    // Is Replaced Video Contaions Blocked Keyword?
    var VideoName = SidebarItems[_count].getElementsByClassName('title');
    if(VideoName.length == 0)
    {
      return;
    }

    if(ValidateString(VideoName[0].innerText))
    {
      SidebarItems[_count].remove();
      continue;
    }

    // Is Replated Video Registered by Blocked Channel?
    var ChannelName = SidebarItems[_count].getElementsByClassName('g-hovercard');
    console.debug(ChannelName);
    console.debug("Element Count = " + ChannelName.length);
    if(ChannelName.length == 0)
    {
      return;
    }

    if(ValidateChannelName(ChannelName[0].innerText))
    {
      SidebarItems[_count].remove();
    }
  }
```

Chrome console shows the ChannelName, and Element Count like this:
[image]

These two results are different, but these are executed simultaneously. more accurate, It seems to `SidebarItems[_count].getElementsByClassName('g-hovercard');` is executed twice, and replaced the result of previous one. As the result, `ChannelName.length == 0` becomes `true`, and `return;` executed.

I don't know how can it be. Stack is going blow up, and My head is going same.

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SidebarItems[_count].getElementsByClassName('g-hovercard');` appears inside a `for` loop.

> ```
> for(_count = 0; _count < SidebarItems.length; _count++)
> ```

Each time the line with `getElementsByClassName` in it gets called, it has a different value of `_count`.

Comment: Then, should I change `SidebarItems.length` to some variables that stores  initial length value?